# Error in Geo location Class

Tags: apex, visualforce

I am getting the follow error`Unknown property 'LeadStandardController.GetAccountsNearLead'`

I am going to call this VF page on the Lead record(button). 
I am thinking the issue is in the Class but the error shows on the VF page. Any guidance is appreciated.

Here is the VF page:

```
<apex:page standardstylesheets="true" showheader="false" standardController="Lead" extensions="LeadGeoController">

   <apex:pageBlock title="Accounts that are near by">
      <apex:pageBlockTable styleClass="responsive-table" value="{!GetAccountsNearLead}" var="accounts">
         <apex:column title="Account Name " value="{!account.name}" headerValue="Name"/>
         <apex:column title="Contacts Email Address " value="{!account.Primary_Contact_Email_Address__c}" headerValue="Email Address"/>   
         <apex:column title="Account Street Address " value="{!account.BillingStreet}" headerValue="Address"/>
         <apex:column title="Account City " value="{!account.BillingCity}" headerValue="City"/>
         <apex:column title="Diectance From Lead " value="{!account.Distance}" headerValue="Distance"/>
      </apex:pageBlockTable>   
</apex:pageBlock>
```

Here is my class

```
public with sharing class LeadGeoController 
 {   
 List<Account> GetAccountsNearLead;
 Account Acct;
 public Decimal lat { get; set; }
 public Decimal longitude{ get; set; 
 } 

 public LeadGeoController (ApexPages.StandardController stdController) {}    


 {
 List<Lead> lat =  [SELECT MALatitude__c from Lead WHERE Id=:ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id')];
 List<Lead> longituide= [SELECT MALongitude__c from Lead WHERE Id=:ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id')];
 }

  public Account GetAccountsNearLead() {
    if (Acct== null) {
      Acct= [SELECT Name,distance(BillingAddress, geolocation(:lat , :longitude), 'mi')  Distance, Primary_Contact_Email_Address__c,BillingStreet,BillingCity
        FROM Account
        WHERE Partner_Type__c= 'TrexPro' AND
        distance(BillingAddress, geolocation(:lat , :longitude), 'mi') < 10 
    //    AND Id = :ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id')
        ORDER BY distance(BillingAddress, geolocation(:lat , :longitude), 'mi')
        LIMIT 5];            
    }
    return Acct;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got a lot of structural problems in this class related to how you name variables and use types.

- Having a method named `GetAccountsNearLead`, returning `Account`, and an instance variable `GetAccountsNearLead` of type `List<Account>` is going to create excessive confusion.
- You also are mixing `Account` and `List<Account>` with your `Acct` variable, which is a single `Account` to which you're assigning a list from your query result.
- You have `Decimal` instance variables called `longitude` and `lat`, but you then use these same names for `List<Lead>` variables in your constructor, and don't do anything with the values you query there. (Those local variables go out of scope at the end of the constructor).
- Starting names with `get` in general is a bad idea, because Visualforce looks for methods names `getPROPERTYNAME` when you reference `{!PROPERTYNAME}` in your page.

Try creating *one* instance variable, `List<Account> accountList { get; set; }`. Use your existing query code from `GetAccountsNearLead()` to populate it in your constructor. Then delete `GetAccountsNearLead()` and the variables `GetAccountsNearLead` and `Acct`, and use `accountList` in your Visualforce page.

Once you've got that working, you can use the same patterns to tackle your other duplicated variables.

For more on how to construct your geolocation queries, please see the Salesforce documentation: [Location-Based SOQL Queries](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_geolocate.htm?search_text=geolocation) and [Using Apex Variables in SOQL and SOSL Queries](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_SOQL_variables.htm).

Comment: Thanks you for the feedback David. I definitely  complicated this Class. So to start cutting into this issue  I am going to start with the Lat and Longitude values.  Can I query the Lead Lat and Longitude field in a single  query to be used in the Account query?

Comment: Yes, you can query both Lead fields in one query.

Comment: Ok David.  Now how do I reference the MALatitude__c  and MALongitude__c fields that I just queried so that I can assign use them in the geolocation(latitude,longitude)?

Comment: Stack Exchange discourages using comment threads for follow-up questions, so I've added some resources in my answer. Please feel free to create new questions as needed.